# Serializing to JSON Large JS Objects

Tags: javascript, serialization

I'm planning on storing JS objects in a database, but objects like navigator return "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when using JSON.stringify(object).

How would I go about serializing to JSON large javascript objects like the navigator object (without pruning)?

Comment: please provide backend and frontend code.  Also include the right code languages. Thanks!

Comment: Consider using a document-based DB, such as MongoDB, and reconsidering how your data is structured.

Comment: it's not the size of navigator that's the issue, it's the self-referential infinite loops that get you.

Comment: @dandavis is right. `navigator` is not a good object to try to serialize into JSON because of its recursive references. If you are using your own objects of any practical size you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put a safety "break" on JSON, using the seldom-used 2nd parameter to JSON.stringify.
this helps to see why navigator never has enough room:

```
var used=[];
var str=JSON.stringify(navigator, function(a,b,c){
  if(used.indexOf(b)===-1 && used.length < 100 ){
     used.push(b);
     return b;
  }
});

alert(str);

//shows: {"geolocation":{},"webkitPersistentStorage":{},"webkitTemporaryStorage":{},"onLine":true,"vendorSub":"","vendor":"Google Inc.","productSub":"20030107","product":"Gecko","mimeTypes":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{"0":{"enabledPlugin":{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

you can get the point after just 100 reps, but it can go all night if only it could...
i bet there is a getter that emits a new object each call, so you never see the same object twice.

changing 100 to 5000 crashes chrome but gives no new properties.

Answer (score 1):

If data is that huge and needs to be inserted to the db then it should definitely be able to be normalized into further sub-entities and grouping which will bring the data to smaller chunks. Then iterating through those groups of data and converting them to json and further saving may help you.

Comment: This is neither an answer nor a logical thought.